# :hover wont work when using display:table-cell on dropdown nav

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, vertical-alignment

i can't figure out why my :hover won't work to change the li color and background color.
I think it worked before i put in display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!!

http://jsfiddle.net/sadaskud/NVLwK/2/

HTML:

```html
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" style="width:100px">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact/a></li>

     <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
     </ul> 

   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
#menu {
background: #03C;
height: 50px;
width: 923px;}

#menu ul {
display: table;
margin:0;padding:0;}

#menu ul a {
text-decoration: none;}

#menu ul li {
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
float: left;}

#menu ul li a {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #fff;
width: 120px;
height: 49px;}

#menu ul ul li {
float: none;
display: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;}

#menu ul ul li a {
background: #3CB6E8;
color: #333;
border:none;}

#menu li a:hover {
color: #ccc;
background:#1F9BD8;}

#menu ul li a:hover, 
#menu ul li:hover ul li {
display:block !important;}
```

Comment: What is the point of the display:block !important at the end? That's obviously what's causing it but why do you have it?

Comment: @zenith: to activate the submenu

Comment: @OneTrickPony I meant including the `#menu ul li a:hover` bit of it - http://jsfiddle.net/NVLwK/5/

Comment: Yeah, that makes no sense. Perhaps OP thought it would add compatibility with IE 7 ?:)

Comment: @Zenith ah thankyou for pointing that out! i got part of this from a template as this is my first attempt at a submenu. It works now

Answer (score 1):

There is no hover state for the li.
The goal is for the li that has the submenu to have a hover state, correct?

```css
#menu li:hover,
#menu li a:hover {
 color: #ccc;
 background:#1F9BD8;
}
```

Comment: `#menu ul li:hover ul li { display:block !important; }` ==> If you take the `a` selector out of this, it doesn't shift on hover...